# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver not found error

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server 2008 database from Java and I'm having the same problem from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461040/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-jdbc-sqlserver-sqlserverdriver).

```
String userName = "xxxx";
String password = "xxxx";
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;databaseName=asdfzxcvqwer;integratedSecurity=true";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

I keep getting a `ClassNotFoundException` Whenever I try to load the driver from `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");`

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at repositories.RepositoryBase.<init>(RepositoryBase.java:22)
    at repositories.ProductsRepository.<init>(ProductsRepository.java:13)
    at api.Products.init(Products.java:31)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've made sure the necessary jdbc and jtds drivers are added to the library and CLASSPATH is set as well. I'm honestly not sure what went wrong here.[image]

Edit: Upon suggestion, I tried to download this [jdbc jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sqlserverjdbc/sqlserverjdbc.jar.zip) and place it in my WEB-INF/lib, then set my CLASSPATH variable to that location. Still, the same problem is happening.[image]

Edit2: Never mind, completely reinstalling Eclipse made it work. This is pretty frustrating...

Comment: Try to include [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sqlserverjdbc/sqlserverjdbc.jar.zip) jar to your classpath

Comment: Mot probably not related: but why do you have the jTDS **and** the Microsoft driver in your classpath? You only need one of them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I misread the tutorial. I've removed it now but still same error.

Comment: As you are using `;integratedSecurity=true` you also need to make sure that `sqljdbc_auth.dll` can be loaded by your class (so it needs to be on `java.library.path`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name java.library.path? Do you mean I need to add the path containing the jar via the `Add External Class Folder` Or set the classpath as a directory path rather than the full path to the jar file? 

But I think my issue comes before the authentication issue as it's not even able to find the class.

Comment: No, not the *jar* the **DLL** - that is if you really want Windows authentication rather than SQL Server authentication. See the manual for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#Connectingintegrated

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh no, I don't want windows authentication. That line was added by mistake and is now removed.

Answer (score 11):

You dont need both jTDS and JDBC in your classpath. Any one is required. Here you need only `sqljdbc.jar`.

Also, I would suggest to place `sqljdbc.jar` at physical location to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project rather than adding it in the Classpath via IDE. Then Tomcat takes care the rest. And also try restarting Tomcat.

You can download Jar from : [www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sqlserverjdbc/sqlserverjdbc.jar.zip](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/sqlserverjdbc/sqlserverjdbc.jar.zip)

EDIT:

As you are supplying Username and Password when connecting,

You need only `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test`, Skip `integratedSecurity` attribute.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking at **sqljdbc4.2** version like :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

but, for **sqljdbc4** version statement should be:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
```

---

I think if you change your first version to write the correct **Class.forName** ,
your application will run.

Comment: Answer checks out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526(v=sql.110).aspx shows one way, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313100 shows the other.

Answer (score 7):

For me, it worked once I changed

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

to:

in POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

and then:

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
```

...

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(SQLServerDriver());    
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

intellij idea 2019

1. Download Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

2. Unpack ("C:\opt\sqljdbc_7.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre11.jar")
3. Add; (File->Project Structure->Global Libraries)
4. Use; (Adding Jar files to IntellijIdea classpath (look video))
   [image: add]
   import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
   [image]
   https://youtu.be/-2hjxoRKsyk

or ub Gradle set "compile"
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '7.2.2.jre11'

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer

```
String userName = "xxxx";
    String password = "xxxx";
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;databaseName=asdfzxcvqwer;integratedSecurity=true";

    try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password); 

  } catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: add a brief explanation please

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbName";
public static final String USERNAME = "xxxx";
public static final String PASSWORD = "xxxx";

/**
 *  This method
    @param args     command line argument
*/
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   try
   {
        Connection connection;
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());   
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(MainDriver.URL,MainDriver.USERNAME,
                        MainDriver.PASSWORD);
        String query ="select * from employee";
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            System.out.print("First Name: " + resultSet.getString("first_name"));
            System.out.println("  Last Name: " + resultSet.getString("last_name"));                
        }
   }catch(Exception ex)
   {
        ex.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after manually copying the sqljdbc4-2.jar into WEB-INF/lib folder.
So please have a try on this too.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a wrong maven dependency deceleration, so here is the correct way:

for **sqljdbc4** use: [sqljdbc4 dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

for **sqljdbc42** use: [sqljdbc42 dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc42/6.0.8112)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc42</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.8112</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

My code base was having

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

it was pulling an older version of `mssql-jdbc`

I replaced it with the below dependency and it worked.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
```