# Java Eclipse JDBC ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to an external database and no matter what I do I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at DbCon.main(DbCon.java:10)
```

My code to set up the driver:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DbCon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried omitting the driver entirely, and just trying to connect with:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433;databaseName=xxxx;user=xxxx;password=xxxx;";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This only gets me the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for xxxx
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at DbCon.main(DbCon.java:15)
```

I've tried adding the jar to Eclipse's classpath, I've added the folder to the project's build path as an external class folder.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241960/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverdriver-not-found-error

Comment: Try simply omitting the call to `Class.forName` and just call `DriverManager.getConnection` with your connection URL. With modern versions of Java and JDBC drivers the `Class.forName` is often unnecessary.

Comment: @Scary I've looked at that, tried those suggestions.

Comment: @Gord When I try that, I get the error "No suitable driver found"

Comment: Did you check the contents of the jar file?  What class is available?

Comment: Which jar? sqljdbc42.jar? What would I be looking for?

Comment: Never mind, I'm not sure what I did, but it seems to be working now. 
I think it was adding the jar directly into the build path.
Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241960/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverdriver-not-found-error)